# How is null behaviour in following method overloading in below code

Tags: java, overloading

I am trying one simple method overloading in java but I cannot figure out the behaviour of "null" when passed as argument  . Or I guess I am missing some theoretical aspect of overloading . Below is my code :

```
public class MethodOverloadNull {
    String met1(Object o) {
        System.out.println("In Objecct O");
        return "hello";
    }

    String met1(String o) {
        System.out.println("In String");
        return "hello";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodOverloadNull obj=new MethodOverloadNull();
        obj.met1(null);
    }
}
```

Output is : `In String`.

But when I commented out overloaded  String arg method I am getting output as : `In Object O`.

```
public class MethodOverloadNull {
    String met1(Object o) {
        System.out.println("In Object O");
        return "hello";
    }

    /*
    String met1(String o) { // commented this method 
        System.out.println("In String");
        return "hello";
    }
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodOverloadNull obj=new MethodOverloadNull();
        obj.met1(null);
    }
}
```

Output :  `In Object O`

Why is this behaviour ???

Comment: java always looks for a more concrete object and enters that one first.

Comment: Why bother? Method overloading is resolved at *compile time*. This means the `null` problem  exists only if you pass a *literal `null`* as parameter. And if you do so in real life code you should be beaten as hard as possible anyway... ;o)